Statistical test for bias in a simulation study to tell if the estimate is biased or unbiased
Say we have a classic simulation study: we choose true parameter value $\theta$, then we generate N datasets and on each of those we run the model we want to test. So we get N estimates $\hat{\theta}_i$ for i = 1..N, including their confidence interval. We can calculate bias:
$$mean(\hat{\theta}_i) - \theta$$
But:

How do we statistically test if the bias is significant or not? To assess whether our model, or estimate procedure, provides biased or unbiased estimates?

I am unable to find any resource on this. E.g. DiRenzo et al. 2023 doesn't resolve this.

I don't think your (2) on bias of confidence intervals is as simple as that.  They can tend to be too wide or too narrow as well as being misaligned.  On (1), you seem to want a parametric test based on the sample estimates of $\theta$, which could require knowing the shape of the distribution of the estimator.

@Henry thanks! I see my point (2) was a too naive idea, deleted it. I am however interested in the statistical test of the bias, as you mention further. Say we have a posterior distribution for the parameter (from each model) - e.g. MCMC samples. And we know the true parameter value. I guess by the "distribution of estimator" you mean a distribution of mean estimates from all those models? How would we statistically test it, then?

If you are happy to make a normal distribution assumption, for just a single
fixed $\theta$ and fixed sample size of the underlying generated data sets ($n$) you can just run a t-test for the null hypothesis $E(\hat\theta)=\theta$. Given that it's a simulation, it may well be that you can generate large enough sample sizes of evaluated estimators $N$ that the Central Limit Theorem will make normality a non-issue.
If you want to aggregate results over different values of $\theta$ and different $n$, the distribution of $\hat\theta$ may depend on these, and the first step would be to understand how that is. The estimator may be equivariant, so $\theta$ may not matter (i.e., results for a single $\theta$ will automatically generalise in that case, and you may also easily aggregate results from different $\theta$). Bias may or may not depend on $n$, but the distribution of $\hat\theta$ will quite certainly depend on it, although it may (or may not) be easy to figure out how. Probably it's better to run separate tests for different $n$, unless you can figure out theoretically what the role of $n$ is.
Note also (chances are you already know that) that a test will never tell you precisely whether its null hypothesis is true or not, so the best thing you can have is the statement that there is no evidence against unbiasedness, which if $N$ is large (and the estimator is so that it generalises over $\theta$ and $n$) can be a pretty strong statement, i.e., you can have a confidence intervall that can be very small.

Thanks Christian! So the t-test is the thing. The distributions are sometimes not normal. How much should I be worried about it with $N$ = 100? PS: yes, it is fixed $\theta$ and $n$, so I don't have to worry about 2nd paragraph. Ad 3rd paragraph, you mean Type I and II errors, power of the test? Yes I'm aware of that :-) Thanks!

Most distributions will be fine with $N=100$ but there can be problems with extreme outliers and extreme skewness (with $N=100$ these problems need to be really very strong to bring the CLT down). So having a look at the distribution of estimators may be good to see whether there's anything worrying.
